# can we use data generator for regression? (Keras, python)

Tags: python-2.7, deep-learning, keras, training-data

I want to augmente my data using data generator in keras as below:

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=True,  # set input mean to 0 over the dataset
    samplewise_center=True,  # set each sample mean to 0
    featurewise_std_normalization=True,  # divide inputs by std of the dataset
    samplewise_std_normalization=True,  # divide each input by its std
    zca_whitening=True,  # apply ZCA whitening
    rotation_range=0,  # randomly rotate images in the range (degrees, 0 to 180)
    rescale=1./255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0,
    width_shift_range=0,  # randomly shift images horizontally (fraction of total width)
    height_shift_range=0,  # randomly shift images vertically (fraction of total height)
    horizontal_flip=True,  # randomly flip images
    vertical_flip=True)  # randomly flip images
```

but I use this network for  regression not classification. I have my doubts that datagenerator set new output values or not? Because If I used 0 or 1 classification problem then datagenerator could flip or rotate data without changing output but in here it should change output like input. Does that do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you use a network with hidden layers it can not be linear. Therefore this cannot be used for linear regression. If you mean for regression, why should your output data be changed? For example if your output is the coolness of an image on a scale from 0 to inf, it often does not matter if the image is translated. What you probably mean is that your output shape matches your input shape. If so you should clarify.

Comment: Yes you are right. I mean regression in general.My problem is suppose I have an image which the output for it is (10,20) when datagen change image for example zoom on it then (10,20) should change because the interest pixel isn't (10,20) now. (For me output of an input image is the specific pixel for example pixel of eye)